# Do two compatible tRNA codons bond together?

Tags: biochemistry, molecular-biology, translation

Can two tRNA with complementary anti-codons link together?  For instance UUU with AAA. If not, why not?

Comment: @Ashafix has given an answer to your question which is technically correct, although it relates to artificial conditions rather than cellular ones. Perhaps this is what you are interested in. However I wonder whether you were thinking about such interaction competing with the interaction of the tRNA anticodon and mRNA codon in the cell. If so, you should make that clear so that we can provide an answer addressing that point.

Answer (score 7):

Yes, tRNA can form dimers. For example it was shown that *E. Coli* tRNA GCC forms homodimers, i.e. two identical molecules interact with each other. In this case the dimerization occurs between the anti-codon loops (what was probably meant with UUU and AAA).

*References:*

- `Sequence and structure of naturally-occurring tRNA transcripts and site-directed variants are significant barriers to forming oligomers beyond dimers.`
  ([Harold S. Bernhardt, Warren P. Tate, *Advances in Bioscience and Biotechnology, 2013, 4, 1-16 ABB*](http://dx.doi.org/10.4236/abb.2013.45A001))
- `Anticodon-anticodon interaction induces conformational changes in tRNA: yeast tRNAAsp, a model for tRNA-mRNA recognition.`([D Moras, A C Dock, P Dumas, E Westhof, P Romby, J P Ebel, and R Giegé, *Proc Natl Acad Sci U S A. 1986 Feb;83(4):932-6*](http://www.pnas.org/content/83/4/932))

A naturally occuring mutation, A3243G in human tRNA(Leu(UUR)), causes dimerization via a motif which is not in the anti-codon loop.

*Reference:*

- [Wittenhagen LM1, Kelley SO., *Nat Struct Biol. 2002 Aug;9(8):586-90.*, 
  Dimerization of a pathogenic human mitochondrial tRNA.](http://dx.doi.org/10.1038/nsb820)

Comment: Link-only answers are generally not acceptable on Stack Exchange sites. The link may change or become unreachable in the future, and without a summary of what the link contains this answer would be useless. Please summarize what is in the link (**don't** just copy and paste) and use the link solely for reference. If you remove the link and the answer cannot stand on its own, it is not a good answer.

Comment: Thanks for the info! I will update the answer later. I thought that giving a reference to a published scientific article would be safe even if the link is dead.

Comment: The reference is fine, and while I only skimmed the article it looks like it may be useful for the OP. We (as in the Stack Exchange community) don't like link-only answers as the link may change or die, but also because it requires you to go to another site and attempt to interpret the research (in this case), which may not be possible for some readers  given the level of their scientific education. Just summarizing the abstract should be fine. One question though - it seemed like the paper only talked about dimers, and couldn't find multimers. You may want to change your answer.